# sparse matrix in EKF SLAM

Tags: slam, ekf

I've successfully done with EKF Localization Algorithm with known and unknown correspondences that are stated in "Probabilistic Robotics". The results make perfect sense,so I can estimate the position of a robot without using GPS or odometry. Now I've moved to EKF-SLAM with known correspondences in the same book. I don't understand this matrix

$$
F_{x,j} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1  & 0  & 0 & 0  \cdots  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cdots 0 \\
0  & 1  & 0 & 0  \cdots  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cdots 0 \\
0  & 0  & 1 & 0  \cdots  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cdots 0 \\
0  & 0  & 0 & 0  \cdots  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cdots 0 \\
0  & 0  & 0 & 0  \cdots  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \cdots 0 \\
0  & 0  & 0 & \underbrace{0  \cdots  0}_{3j-3} & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \underbrace{0 \cdots 0}_{3N-3j} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
What is exactly the bottom of this matrix? The following
$$
F_{x,j} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0  \cdots  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cdots 0 \\
0  \cdots  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \cdots 0 \\
\underbrace{0  \cdots  0}_{3j-3} & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \underbrace{0 \cdots 0}_{3N-3j} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is it as following (assuming N = 3)
$$
F_{x,j} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Or 
$$
F_{x,j} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where ones' represent a specific landmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly your second guess, i.e.:

$$
F_{x,j} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If you pay attention, the columns that are repeated (with `...`) contain all zeros, both the first column and the last.

If they wanted to show your first guess, they would have written something like this:

$$
F_{x,j} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1  \cdots  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \cdots 0 \\
0  \cdots  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \cdots 0 \\
\underbrace{0  \cdots  1}_{N} & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \underbrace{0 \cdots 1}_{N} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Note that now the first element of the first column is 1 and the last element of the last column is also 1, showing that the 1 moves from top to bottom on each column. Note also that the number of columns (previously `3j-3` and `3N-3j`) are now changed to `N` (the number of rows, let's assume) because otherwise the pattern and the number of columns would be inconsistent.

Comment: Is it 3j-3 or 2j-2? Is it 3N-3j or 2N-2j? I found 2j-2 and 2N-2j in the book.